# VLFeat: vlmodulo_2pi_f function

Tags: c, sift, vlfeat

I am trying to understand the inner workings of the VLFeat SIFT algorithm and I notice this statement when computing the image gradient:

```
 *grad++ = vl_mod_2pi_f   (vl_fast_atan2_f (gy, gx) + 2*VL_PI);
```

I am wondering if this expression is not the same as `vl_fast_atan2_f (gy, gx)` as we are adding `2 PI` and the modulo of the expression on RHS should evaluate to `atan2(gy, gx)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`vl_fast_atan2_f` is an approximated (and thus faster) version of `atan2` (see [this doc](http://www.vlfeat.org/api/mathop_8h.html#a302745de850d5b18b49359a830b74f6d) for more details).

Still it returns results in `[-pi, pi]` so adding `2.pi` and take the modulus (`vl_mod_2pi_f`) rescales the result into `[0, 2.pi]` which is how the gradient angle is represented.